# 2D array of structs in heap memory C

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I keep getting a segfault when I try to initialize a 2D array of structs in dynamic memory. I know a 1D array of structs is technically a pointer to a pointer, I figured a 2D array of structs also functioned that way, but it seems like maybe not?

Code:

```
typedef struct PTE {
    unsigned int faddr:7;           
    unsigned int present:1;
    unsigned int wp:1;
    unsigned int mod:1;
    unsigned int ref:1;
    unsigned int pout:1;
    unsigned int fmap:1;
} PTE; 

void init_pte(PTE **pgtbl_l, int num_ps) {
// Initialize all fields to zero
    for (int i=0; i<num_ps; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<64; j++) {
            PTE *new_pte = malloc(sizeof(PTE));
            pgtbl_l[i][j] = *new_pte;
            new_pte->faddr = 0;
            new_pte->present = 0;
            new_pte->wp = 0;
            new_pte->mod = 0;
            new_pte->ref = 0;
            new_pte->pout = 0;
            new_pte->fmap = 0;
        }
    }
}

void print_pagetable(PTE **pgtbl_l, int num_ps) {
    for (int i=0; i<num_ps; i++) {
        printf("PT[%d]: ", i);
        for (int j=0; j<64; j++) {
            printf("faddr: %d pres: %d wp: %d mod: %d ref %d", pgtbl_l[i][j].faddr,
                   pgtbl_l[i][j].present, pgtbl_l[i][j].wp, pgtbl_l[i][j].mod,
                   pgtbl_l[i][j].ref);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

PTE *pgtbl_l[num_ps][64];                   
init_pte(pgtbl_l, num_ps); 
print_pagetable(pgtbl_l, num_ps);
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "a 1D array of structs is technically a pointer to a pointer". That does not match my understanding. Maybe show a declaration of a "1D array of structs" for reference/comparison and contrast it to a declaration of a 2D array of structs, a 1D array of int and a 2D array of int.

Comment: I thought if you initialize an array of structs and want to create it dynamically you have to initialize it as `STRUCT *mystruct[10];` and pass it as int `myfunc(**mystruct);`

Comment: @ThomasM That's an array of *pointers to structs*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointers and arrays are not the same thing.  In many cases, an array *decays* to a pointer to its first element, however this does not flow down to multidimentional arrays.

So for a 1D array you can do this:

```
char A[5];
char *p = A;
```

But for a 2D array:

```
char A[5][6];
char (*p)[6] = A;
```

In the latter case, `A` is an array of size 5, where each element is an array of size 6.  So the array to pointer decay happens on only the first dimension.

You need to change you function definitions to:

```
void init_pte(PTE pgtbl_l[][64], int num_ps) {
```

And:

```
void print_pagetable(PTE pgtbl_l[][64], int num_ps) {
```

Comment: ok, thanks, I'll try that. should i still initialize it as `PTE *pgtbl_l[num_ps][64];`?

Comment: @ThomasM No, it should be `PTE pgtbl_l[num_ps][64];`

Comment: and pass it as: `init_pte(pgtbl_l, num_ps);`?

Comment: @ThomasM Yes, pass it the same way.